# How to combine duplicate rows into a Single Row unique Identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

How do I combine duplicate rows with different values using unique identifiers.

I've created the created SQL Query but limited knowledge in SQL Language

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), aualdocs.doc_typ)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(5), aualdocs.doc_yer)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(5), aualdocs.doc_num)
    + '.'+ CONVERT(varchar(5), aualdocs.doc_prt) as 'Project No'
  , aualdocs.det_dte AS 'Approval Date'
  , auallnks.acc_dsc AS 'Project Owner'
  , auprparc.ttl_in1 AS 'Lot No'
  , aualadrs.hou_num AS 'House Number'
  , aualadrs.str_nme AS 'Street'
  , aualadrs.sbr_nme AS 'Suburb'
  , aualadrs.pst_cde AS 'Postcode'
  , aualrefn.dsc_no1 AS 'Description Of Works'
  , audmptyp.est_cst AS 'Value Of Works'
from aualdocs aualdocs
INNER JOIN audmptyp audmptyp on aualdocs.fmt_acc=audmptyp.mdu_fmt
INNER JOIN auallnks auallnks on aualdocs.fmt_acc=auallnks.src_acc
INNER JOIN auprlink auprlink on aualdocs.fmt_acc=auprlink.mdu_fmt
INNER JOIN aualrefn aualrefn on aualdocs.ddn_cd2=aualrefn.ref_val
LEFT JOIN aupraddr aupraddr on auprlink.pcl_num=aupraddr.pcl_num
LEFT JOIN auprparc auprparc on auprlink.pcl_num=auprparc.pcl_num
LEFT JOIN aualadrs aualadrs on aupraddr.aladrs_key_num=aualadrs.key_num
where aualdocs.doc_typ='6' and aualdocs.det_cde='ADA'
and auallnks.lnk_typ='152' and aualrefn.ref_typ='bld_typ'
and audmptyp.est_cst>0 order by aualdocs.fmt_acc ASC
```

The results I've achieved are as the picture

[image: SQL Query Results]

What I'm trying to achieve is as example attached

[image: Result to Achieve]

Comment: You need a reporting tool to group and display your data the way you want displayed. Not possible in just SQL.

Comment: Use excel then?

Comment: yes you can use Excel ..

Comment: This is responsibility of UI to display combined rows, not SQL. Use your current query to retrieve data then manipulate it to display as desired.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, will have to look into this further.

Comment: The closest you'll get in SQL Server is combining values from the duplicate rows into one string using newline characters so they display one on top of the other. Now I'm not saying you should do this, @Harry is correct in saying this is one of the front end. Just depends on your use case...